# How do I edit properties of components?

Tags: java, android, android-button

Let's say I have a button. How would I programmatically edit its properties? I don't want to change the properties using XML code in the layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your Button variable:

```
Button button;
...
```

Then write the following in your onCreate() method:

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.<Your buttons ID>);
button.setHeight(50);
```

Please rather do research before asking questions.

Comment: I think it should be button.setHeight(50) instead of button.setHeight = 50 :)